# redux-saga-test-plan Failing Assert with exact expected and actual

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I have a createPostSaga which `POST`s to my API and I am trying to test it. This is the saga:

```
export function* createPostSaga(action) {
  const token = yield select(selectToken);
  const headerParams = {
    Authorization: `JWT ${token}`
  };
  const apiCall = () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", action.payload.title);
    formData.append("content", action.payload.content);
    formData.append("thumbnail", action.payload.thumbnail);
    formData.append("tags", JSON.stringify(action.payload.tags));
    formData.append("slug", generateSlug(action.payload.title));
    return axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/posts/",
      data: formData,
      headers: headerParams
    })
      .then(response => response.data)
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  };

  try {
    const response = yield call(apiCall);
    yield put(push(`/posts/${response.id}/${response.slug}/`));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

and this is the code I have so far that is failing:

```
describe("createPostSaga", () => {
    const action = {
      type: types.CREATE_POST,
      payload: {
        title: "test title",
        pub_date: "2018-11-12",
        content: "test content",
        tags: ["test1", "test2"],
        thumbnail: "http://fail",
        slug: "test-title"
      }
    }

    const apiCall = () => ({
      id: 1,
      ...action.payload  
    });

    it("calls the api and redirects", () => {
      testSaga(actions.createPostSaga, action)
        .next()
        .select(selectToken)
        .next()
        .call(apiCall)
        .next()
        .put(push("/posts/1/test-title/"))
        .finish()
        .isDone();
    })
  })
```

When I test this code, I receive the following error:

```
SagaTestError:
    Assertion 2 failed: call effects do not match

    Expected
    --------
    { context: null, fn: [Function: apiCall], args: [] }

    Actual
    ------
    { context: null, fn: [Function: apiCall], args: [] }
```

As you can see the expected and actual results are the same.

I have also tried to directly copy paste the `apiCall` function into my test but it fails with the same message and I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Before testing, you should refactor your code. Extract the `apiCall` function from the `createPostSaga` generator function, you should keep using the same `apiCall` function both in the `createPostSaga` and the test case.

Besides, you are using the `testSaga` function to do unit testing, but we still need to provide mock return value for `yield select(selectToken)` and `yield call(apiCall, action, headerParams)`.  We can do this by calling the `.next(mockValue)` function and passing a value to it.

The final working example:

`saga.ts`:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { call, put, select } from "redux-saga/effects";

export const selectToken = state => state.token;
export const push = (payload) => ({ type: 'PUSH', payload })

export const apiCall = (action, headerParams) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("title", action.payload.title);
  formData.append("content", action.payload.content);
  formData.append("thumbnail", action.payload.thumbnail);
  formData.append("tags", JSON.stringify(action.payload.tags));
  formData.append("slug", action.payload.title);
  return axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "/posts/",
    data: formData,
    headers: headerParams
  })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
};

export function* createPostSaga(action) {
  const token = yield select(selectToken);
  const headerParams = {
    Authorization: `JWT ${token}`
  };
  try {
    const response = yield call(apiCall, action, headerParams);
    yield put(push(`/posts/${response.id}/${response.slug}/`));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { testSaga } from "redux-saga-test-plan";
import * as actions from './saga'
import { apiCall, push, selectToken } from "./saga";

const types = {
  CREATE_POST: 'CREATE_POST'
}

describe('53423270', () => {
  const action = {
    type: types.CREATE_POST,
    payload: {
      title: "test title",
      pub_date: "2018-11-12",
      content: "test content",
      tags: ["test1", "test2"],
      thumbnail: "http://fail",
      slug: "test-title"
    }
  }

  it("calls the api and redirects", () => {
    testSaga(actions.createPostSaga, action)
      .next()
      .select(selectToken)
      .next('fakeTokenAbcd123')
      .call(apiCall, action, { Authorization: 'JWT fakeTokenAbcd123' })
      .next({ id: '1', slug: 'test-title' })
      .put(push("/posts/1/test-title/"))
      .finish()
      .isDone();
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS   redux-saga-examples  packages/redux-saga-examples/src/stackoverflow/53423270/saga.test.ts
  53423270
    ✓ calls the api and redirects (3 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   59.26 |      100 |   33.33 |      50 |                   
 saga.ts  |   59.26 |      100 |   33.33 |      50 | 8-22,35           
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.535 s
```

package versions:

```json
"redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
"redux-saga-test-plan": "^4.0.1",
"jest": "^27.0.6",
"axios": "^1.1.3"
```